# how to pass arguments of powershell in Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins

this is my PS script

```
Function Publish
{
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $RELEASEDIR,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $SERVICENAME,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $SERVER
    )
Get-ChildItem "$RELEASEDIR\*"
$service = Get-Service -Name $SERVICENAME -Computername $SERVER -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$service.Status
}
```

I am trying to call PS script from Jenkins server.PS script has few arguments to get passed. Like..

```
PS C:\Release\RPCPS> Publish -RELEASEDIR "C:\Release\Batchfile" -SERVICENAME "AmazonSSMAgent" -SERVER "10.0.1.91"
```

how to pass arguments of powershell script in Jenkins.

While I use below set Up. My Jenkins jobs is not able to read it. So please guide me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call powershell exe if you have installed the powershell plugin, and for your stuff to work, dot source your script

```
. "path to script"
Publish -arg1 -arg2 -arg3
```